# How do you export data?

Tags: cognito-forms

When I go to entries and see the entire list of all my entries, there is an export button at the top.  When I click the export button, nothing happens.  I've tried with Firefox and Chrome.  I can see the browser does a quick "loading" action when I click the button, but nothing attempts to download.  I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a temporary issue affecting export this evening.  This has been resolved.  Just click export (in any modern browser) and it should work just fine now.

Comment: Sure enough you are correct. Today it magically works as expected. Just bad luck that my first time using the product that it wasn't working.

Comment: Extremely!  We identified the issue almost immediately after it was introduced through a performance release.  Glad everything is working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox on a PC, Windows 10.  When I click on Export, a little window pops up in the lower left screen asking whether I want to open or save the file.